# Python API limit exceeded despite increasing amount of second

Tags: python, quota

I am trying to learn the python api for news sources so I copied the python notebook code from here: [source](https://github.com/brienna/coronavirus-news-analysis/blob/master/2020_05_01_get_data_from_NYT.ipynb)

When I run the code, exactly as posted except for the api key, I see the error below (the quote limit is 10).  It appears even when I expend to 30 seconds from 6.  I am not sure why this error appears because it did not appear for the code creator (their entire response was posted).  Sorry for my dumb questions, I am a novice.

```
This is my error message:  
Working on ['2015-01-01', '00:00:00']...
Working on ['2015-02-01', '00:00:00']...
Working on ['2015-03-01', '00:00:00']...
Working on ['2015-04-01', '00:00:00']...
Working on ['2015-05-01', '00:00:00']...
Working on ['2015-06-01', '00:00:00']...
Working on ['2015-07-01', '00:00:00']...
Working on ['2015-08-01', '00:00:00']...
Working on ['2015-09-01', '00:00:00']...
Working on ['2015-10-01', '00:00:00']...
Working on ['2015-11-01', '00:00:00']... <--  Always stops here 

in parse_response
{'fault': {'faultstring': 'Rate limit quota violation. Quota limit  exceeded. 'detail': {'errorcode': 'policies.ratelimit.QuotaViolation'}}}
{'headline': [], 'date': [], 'doc_type': [], 'material_type': [], 'section': [], 'keywords': []}
```

url comparison:

works at nyt api:
https://api.nytimes.com/svc/archive/v1/2019/1.json?api-key=YOUR_API_KEY

code generated url states access denied even though I have access to NYT archive:

https://api.nytimes.com/svc/archive/v1/2016-01-01/00:00:00.json?api-key=YOUR_API_KEY

'''fixed url new error message when running from python'''

IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

but works in browser:  https://api.nytimes.com/svc/archive/v1/2016/1.json?api-key=YOUR_API_KEY

I saw others asking this question with google but this is nytimes.

Thanx

Comment: The `sleep()` isn't executed if an `Exception` is raised. It's possible that enough of your requests raise exceptions after sending that you exceed the short-term limit of 10 r/min. It's also possible that you've exceeded the 4000 r/day limit.

Comment: I am using a smaller date range than the original code and less than 4000 requests per day so this is confusing.  I updated my error message

Comment: Suspiciously, it's the 11th request which fails. Note that your code doesn't print `"Saving ..."`, this tells me that each of the responses is `None` and my suspicion about `Exception`s is correct.

Comment: You are correct, it is going to the exception  due to urls.  I compared urls and added them above.  The working one is when I use my key in the NYT api site.  The nonworking one is from the code.  Do you know why the second url is not working?

Comment: The second URL is invalid because it doesn't follow the format: `/{year}/{month}.json`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.nytimes.com/docs/archive-product/1/overview), it tells you how to format URLs.

Comment: The second URL should be `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/archive/v1/2016/1.json?api-key=YOUR_API_KEY`, this will request everything from January 2016.

Comment: I see what the problem is further.  I think a python library must have changed since the code was posted last year.  Using the original code, the author generates dates of :  [['1851', '1'],
 ['1851', '2'],   but when I use the SAME code, I see this:    [['1851-01-01', '00:00:00'],
 ['1851-02-01', '00:00:00'],

Comment: I was able to remove time and shorten the date but I cannot remove the leading zero in the month, now it looks like this [['1851,', '01'],
 ['1851,', '02'].   Do you know how to remove the leading zero in the month?  I changed the code to: for x in pd.date_range(start, end, freq='MS').strftime("%Y, %m").tolist()]?

Comment: You can access the month via the `date` object's `month` attribute: `d = date.today()`, `month = d.month`. Note that the `month` attribute is an `int` so you need to cast it to `str` prior to building your URL.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it finally works!!!!  There is so much old python code online.

Comment: My pleasure. Yes, there is much old code online in general, and there is also much crappy code online. For Python, I usually shy away from Jupyter notebooks and anything Anaconda because I find the authors' code quality to be lower than average, just a generalization, I know plenty of talented programmers who use these tools well and serve as exceptions to my generalization.

Comment: Really what I'm saying is "take code you find online with a grain of salt."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you wait regardless of whether an `Exception` is raised:

```py
def send_request(date):
    '''Sends a request to the NYT Archive API for given date.'''
    base_url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/archive/v1/'
    url = base_url + '/' + date[0] + '/' + date[1] + '.json?api-key=' + YOUR_API_KEY
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, verify=False).json()
    except Exception:
        return None
    finally:
        time.sleep(6)
    return response
```

The `finally` clause is the last block of code executed before the `try` or `except` blocks complete. This means that the `finally` block will execute before any `return` statement in the `try`, `except` or `else` (not applicable here) blocks. This can be very confusing. I suggest putting a single `return` statement at the end of the function like this:

```py
def send_request(date):
    '''Sends a request to the NYT Archive API for given date.'''
    base_url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/archive/v1/'
    url = base_url + '/' + date[0] + '/' + date[1] + '.json?api-key=' + YOUR_API_KEY
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, verify=False).json()
    except Exception:
        response = None
    finally:
        time.sleep(6)
    return response
```

Both will have the same result: sleep six seconds regardless of the response and return either a `Response` or `None`, but I think the second is easier to understand. Now, you still need to figure out why the `Exception`s are occurring and fix that. I suggest adding some `print()` debugging statements in the `except` block to figure out exactly what's occurring.

Another option would be to assume that the reader fully understands Python's try-except-else-finally behavior:

```py
def send_request(date):
    '''Sends a request to the NYT Archive API for given date.'''
    base_url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/archive/v1/'
    url = base_url + '/' + date[0] + '/' + date[1] + '.json?api-key=' + YOUR_API_KEY
    try:
        return requests.get(url, verify=False).json()
    except Exception:
        return None
    finally:
        time.sleep(6)
```

This [article](https://python.plainenglish.io/caveats-of-using-return-with-try-except-in-python-1f21cadbfa00) does an excellent job of explaining the behavior of Python's try-except-else-finally behavior.